# Threaded Socket Server Private Message

Tags: sockets, pthreads, mutex

I've been delving recently into threaded socket servers. Unfortunately I have yet to find the code wherein a user can PM or private message another. Since each is connected via a thread I've been searching for a way to modify a thread's variables with no joy. Do I have to make a global variable holding all messages that each thread parses through (with a mutex)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need some kind of shared data structure, protected by a mutex.

It doesn't need to be a global, but all the connection-handling threads will need a reference to it.  A global would accomplish that, but so would a data structure allocated in the main thread, with a reference to it passed to each thread as it was created.

Presuming that your threads are written to block on the socket that they are reading from, the tricky part is going to be waking them up when there's a new (internal) message for them.  The easiest way to solve that is probably to create a `pipe()` for each thread, and have the threads block in `select()` on the socket that they're handling and their pipe.  You can then send them private messages over the pipe, and the shared data structure will only be to look up the connected users and find the file descriptor for their pipe.